# jQuery and PHP undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good day everyone!

I'm trying to load an external `php` file using `jQuery` and I'm getting an `undefined index` because clearly I'm using a `GET` method in my external php file.

Here is my code:

**main file**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#loadClients').load('clientsTable.php');
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="loadClients"><!-- load here--></div>
</body>
```

**clientsTable.php**

```
<table class="searchTbl" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="200">Account #</th>
      <th width="300">Customer Name</th>
      <th width="150">Balance</th>
      <th width="100">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      require ("db.php");
      $add = $_GET['address'];
      if ($_GET['address']=="All") 
      {
      $gets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers");
      }
      else
      {
      $gets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cusadd='$add'");
      }
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gets))
      {
      ?>
    <tr>
      <td> <?= $row['accno']; ?> </td>
      <td> <?= $row['name']; ?> </td>
      <!-- <td style="color:#f0356e; "> <?php //number_format($row['totbal']); ?> </td> -->
      <td style="color:#f0356e; "> <?= formatMoney($row['totbal'], true); ?> </td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="records.php?id=<?= $row['accno']; ?>" id="viewData-<?= $row['accno']; ?>"> View Data </a> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my main file, the sample url is `localhost/accountsknc/main.php?address=All`. The error/notice I'm getting is `Notice: Undefined index: address` because maybe it's an external file.

Is there a way to handle this so that the data of the clients will show up in my main file? Thank you in advance.

PS: I know that my code is vulnerable because mysql is getting deprecated but I'm only testing this locally and will use PDO when I will implement it already.

Comment: Your main file says `clientsTable.php`, which one is it?

Comment: @MinusFour that is the external file

Comment: You are mixing up requests. If your first request is `main.php?address=All`, any subsequent request (i.e. the load) won't be sending the query string unless you specify so.

Answer (score 1):

The error because no such params  with `address` name exist on url, thus `$_GET['address']` are not exist and can't get the value which will end up with error. Give it some value if did't get the request :

```
<?php
require ("db.php");
$add = isset( $_GET['address'] ) ?  $_GET['address'] : 'All';
if ($add=="All") 
{
  $gets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers");
}
else
{
  $gets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cusadd='$add'");
}
```

Comment: With your code, whatever address is equal to, it becomes "All"

Comment: No, it should not. How you call it? Can you post the mentioned url

Comment: If it's main.php?address=All it should show all the clients, but for example if it's main.php?address=Alabama, it should only show clients from Alabama

Comment: If i understand your case correctly, right now you have `main.php` page that call the page `clientsTable.php` by using jquery load. And the url of current browsing for example is `main.php?address=Albama` and you want this `Albama` value available inside the code you called from jquery load right?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Then, it does not work. The page you called from jquery only react the url from this `$('#loadClients').load('clientsTable.php');` call. Not the url of current browsing page. You get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104942/discussion-between-fewflyby-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a small modification to these two lines.

```
$add = $_GET['address'];
if ($_GET['address']=="All")
```

To

```
$add = isset($_GET['address']) ? $_GET['address'] : 'All';
if($add == "All")
```

Therefore, if the $_GET['address'] is not set, it'll look for all address as if your $_GET['address'] is "All".

Comment: With your code, whatever address is equal to, it becomes "All"

Comment: What? Why would if become "All"? If $_GET['address'] is set, it's going to take the $_GET['address'] value, otherwise it's going to take "All" as a value.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.. whatever the address is equal to, it still gets all of the addresses

Comment: Can you show me what you tried?